# Sending invitations from a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-events

I run the Facebook page for a local high school sports team, and every time I've ever gone to send out invitations to one of our events, the invitation comes through as "[My Name] invited you to [Team]'s event [Event Name]."

Is there a way to make the invitation come from the page itself instead of me? As the administrator, I know I have the option of switching between the page and my personal profile when commenting and posting, but I haven't figured out how/if I can do that when it comes to event invites (or inviting people to like the page, for that matter).

I'd love for the notification format to be "[Team] invited you to their event [Event Name]" or "[Team] invited you to like their page." Is it possible to do this?